# git - from a local branch how to pull down commits from master

Tags: git, github

i actually do not work on master. i work off a develop. The entire team works on develop. I am creating a feature so i created a local feature branch called "feature/myAnalytics".

Now the feature is complete but our team works off of pull requests and i want to ensure that there is not much merge issues.  How can i pull down the changes from develop into my local branch and fix any merge conflicts. After that i'll push the branch up to the remote and do a pull request.

i was thinking to do `git rebase`. i think if i do rebase it will change the history of my local branch and automatically merge the local branch into develop right ?  but could also just do from my local branch `git pull origin develop` and fix the conflicts this way ? is it safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear . 
You are working on a branch "feature/myAnalytics " woven out from the master "develop" ? 
Then , I believe you should pull from develop branch to your local feature branch using :-

'git pull origin develop'

Comment: so i should checkout the "feature/myanalytics" and afterwards run git pull origin develop ? and this will merge the changes of develop into my local branch ?

Comment: Since you are working on "feature/myAnalytics" , I presume it should be already checked out and you will be in that current space.

Comment: The process I follow is :- 1. I checkout to that branch . 2. Pull from that branch into my local system . 3 Pull from the master branch to that local system. 4. Resolve any merge conflict produced in (3) . 5. Commit and Push my merged and updated changes into the feature branch. 6. Create a pull request and merge.